# How do I extract `$Platform` and `$config` from the dproj file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to extend [GPProfile](http://code.google.com/p/gpprofile2011/wiki/GpProfile) so it also works with XE2.

The problem why it does not is that it does not know how to translate the file path in XE2's .dproj file.

The following error occurs:

> Exception class EOSError with message TGpHugeFile.AccessFile(C:\Users\Johan\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\project8\ **$(Platform)\$(Config)** \Project8.gpd) failed. Win32 Error.  Code: 3.
>   System cannot find the given path.'

The program extracts the path, but does not know how to translate the `$platform` and `$config` variables.

Whilst it's easy enough to hardcode these vars to `Win32/Win64` and `Release/Debug` respectively, I'd like to do it properly. By which I mean that I want to extract the values that the IDE saves to the .dproj file which are the selected values of the variables when the files is saved.

**How do I extract the these values from the `.dproj` file?**

Comment: You cannot do this. We routinely pass the .dproj file to msbuild and specify the values of these variables. The values don't exist until you compile. The list of possible values is present in the .dproj file. Read the file to work out where they live. The last values selected in the IDE might be present, or might not.

Comment: I have an application is misleading. You are trying to port Primoz's profiler to more modern Delphi. Hasn't anyone else done that? An instrumenting profiler is exactly what you do not want mind you, looking at your previous question.

Comment: So how does the IDE remember these values upon reopen then?

Comment: Read my first comment. They are in the .dproj file, if there was an active config/platform when you saved. You did not say that you wanted that specific value. You asked for the value, and of course it depends who is supplying the value. Not everything is done in the IDE.

Comment: Fixed the question, no the latest version it supports is Delphi XE. I'm done updating to XE2 and it works, it's just that the vars are hardcoded to `Win32` and `Release` in the source. 
With regards to the type of profiler, I'd like to have options so whilst I'm on the hunt might as well finish it.

Comment: Question not quite fixed. You need to make it clear which specific values you are after. It's very easy to answer the question. You can do it yourself with a diff program. And then an XML parser.

Comment: Sorry, I do want that value because I always use the IDE, but I see the point that for other people's sake I also need to add an option to choose in the UI of GPProfile.

Comment: Yes, the diff tool would do the job, did not think of that, thanks

Comment: OK updated the source and the tool works under XE2, emailed the updates to Primoz.

Comment: also see: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/18/dproj-changed-or-not-changed/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work this out with a little reverse engineering. Take a default project and add the Win64 platform. Then save the .dproj file. Then change the values of both platform and config, and save another .dproj file. Then run these files through a difference program. The output looks like this:

```
8,9c8,9
<                       <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Debug</Config>
<                       <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
---
>                       <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Release</Config>
>                       <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win64</Platform>
```

Now that you know where the values live, it's just a simple XML parsing task to extract them from the file.

---

Now for a rant. If anyone from Emba reads this, would it be possible to change the program to store the settings from the IDE in a different file? Perhaps named .dproj.local or .dproj. or similar. That would allow us to commit the .dproj file to revision control and not have it show up as modified every time we switch platforms for a debugging session.

Comment: Thanks, that was too easy.

Comment: @David Does 'Option Sets' (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Option_Sets_Overview) help out at all?

Comment: @NicholasRing Well, they help in other ways, but they don't change anything related to my rant.

Comment: There are a lot of silly things in the .dproj file that should have been in .dproj.local, even paths to packages that are unique to your own machine.

Answer (score 1):

`$(Platform)`, `$(Config)` and other `$(...)` environment variables are set by the compiler when the project is being compiled.  The .dproj contains paths that get translated dynamically during compiling.  If you need to extract the paths and do something with them, you will have to manually translate the environment variables yourself before then using the final translated paths.  You will likely need to have GPProfile prompt the user for the relevant Platform/Config values as needed.

Comment: But... Delphi XE2 remembers my settings for $Platform and $Config when I reopen my project. So it must store this data somewhere. If not in the .dproj file then in some other location. Surely this must be extractable somehow?

Comment: It does store the latest IDE value, if one exists. I said that in my comment. You weren't clear that's what you wanted. It sucks big time that the IDE does this. Mix in revision control and it's a total mess. All you need to do to reverse engineer this is to use a difference program. It's really that simple!